# Teradata, subquery in case

Tags: sql, subquery, case, teradata

can you help me please. I need insert in case subquery, but teradata doesn't allow me this query, how can i change it (to similar query as case, like if)?

```
select amount, status
case
when max(amount) then 
(select sum(a1.amount)+a2.amount
from payments a1
join  payments a2 on a1.payment_id=a2.payment_id
where a2.status = 't'
and a1.status not like 'w'
group by  a1.amount,a2.amount)
else sum(amount)
end
from payments
```

`Amount | Status
--------| ------
10      | t
20      | w
30      | t
40      | w
50      | t
60      | t
70      | k`

expected results: if amount is max then calculate amount to new column like sum(a1.amount)+a2.amount, where status for table a1 is 't' and status for a2 is not 'w'. If amount is not max, then just calculate all amounts from table payments.

results:

--for amount = 70 insert into new column (for example result) sum(all amount where status is not 'w') + sum(all amount where status is 't').

--For other amount < 70 insert into new column result sum(all amount).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Too many errors... Show us some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your attempt at a query simply does not explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help I guess

```
select  amt,status,(case when amt=max_amt then w_sum else total_sum end)results
from (
select  amt,
           status,
           sum(amt) over(partition by (case when status='w' and status<>'t' then 1 else 0 end   ))w_sum,
           sum(amt) over(partition by 1) total_sum,
           max(amt) over(partition by 1) max_amt
from    t st)x
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: thank you very much, it works!!! You answered to my question, but i have one more question. If I change total_sum and w_sum (in `(case when amt=max_amt then total_sum else w_sum end)` and in subquery total_sum and w_sum), then I have 3 results (when amount is max, when amount is not max and when status is 't') It should be just 2 results (when amount is max and amount is not max)... can you help me please, what i should change?

Comment: try this: Okay. Try this now:                                                                           `select  amount,status,(case when amount=max_amt then total_sum else w_sum end)results
from (
select amount,
           status,
           sum(case when status ='t' then amount else 0 end ) over(partition by 1)w_sum,
           sum(amount) over(partition by 1) total_sum,
           max(amount) over(partition by 1) max_amt
from payments )x`   ...accept the answer if it deserves.

Comment: thank you very much :) it woks :) trifling error in `sum(case when status ='t' then amount else 0 end )`, here must be `sum(case when status ='t' then 0 else amount end )` Thank you very much!